# How to set permissions to list directories in a Xamarin forms application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Could anyone please help explain the following behavior in a Xamarin forms app?

In my MainActivity.cs file, if I call the following function:

```
string szPicturesDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;
```

I get:

"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures"

Ok, that's fine. If I now call:

```
var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("/storage/");
List<string> workDirs = new List<string>(dirs);
```

I get:

[image]

That's fine too.

But if instead I call:

```
var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(szPicturesDirectory);
```

I get:

[image]

I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml file but still same error. The whole file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.oglmobile">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="OGLMobile.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#:~:text=The%20ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE%20intent%20action%2C%20available%20on%20Android%205.0,configure%20each%20use%20case.%20Create%20a%20new%20file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Android 6 (API 23)` or higher, the permission is requested at the run time during the runnnig of the app.

Try to request the `WriteExternalStorage` runtime permission.

in your MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       ...
      if (CheckSelfPermission( Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted)
      {
         string szPicturesDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;
         var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(szPicturesDirectory);
         List<string> workDirs = new List<string>(dirs);
      }
      else
      {
         ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(Instance, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 1);
      }
     ...
    }

 public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1)
        {
            if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
            {
                string szPicturesDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;
                var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(szPicturesDirectory);
                List<string> workDirs = new List<string>(dirs);
            }
        }
    }
```